# Error when I try to insert a timestamp value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I am trying to insert the following value

```
('PA', 'Hilda Blainwood', 3, 10.7, 4308.20, '9/8/1974', '9:00', '07/03/1996 10:30:00');
```

into table **alltypes** with the following structure

```
create table alltypes( state CHAR(2), name CHAR(30), children INTEGER, distance FLOAT,
budget NUMERIC(16,2), checkin TIME, started TIMESTAMP);
```

the following error pops up

```
test=# insert into alltypes VALUES('PA', 'Hilda Blainwood', 3, 10.7, 4308.20, '9/8/1974',
'9:00', '07/03/1996 10:30:00');
ERROR:  INSERT has more expressions than target columns
LINE 1: ...Blainwood', 3, 10.7, 4308.20, '9/8/1974', '9:00', '07/03/199...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is pretty self explanatory: you're trying to insert more values that the table has columns. Your table has seven columns but your VALUES expression has eight values.

BTW, you should always specify the columns when you INSERT:

```
insert into alltypes (state, name, children, distance, budget, checkin, started)
values (...)
```